# XNA 4.0 ClickOnce game does not run after installation

Tags: xna, installation, clickonce

Okay, I have been looking all over to solve this problem before I actually broke down and decided to finally ask for my psecific problem. I am using ClickOnce installation and when I use the setup.exe to install nothing runs, not even on my personal computer that I know has all of the proper libraries and such. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong so it is difficult to explain the problem.

I have included dotNetFramework4.0 client x86 x64 , xna redistributable 4.0 and windows installer 3.1 along with my game and I have it set to install all of that with setup , also I have it set to download prereqs from same location as application. I've tried it on three separate computers , one that does not have XNA or VS C# installed and the same problem occurs.

> > Here is the problem , after I install the game nothing runs, I try clicking on the ClickOnce application file (the one with my game's icon image) and again nothing happens. The thing that really bugs me is that there isn't any errors or crashes or anything , it's almost like clicking on the desktop screen. (I looked at the properties of the "shortcut" that was installed with the game and the file size of the shortcut is like 300 bytes. Isn't that really small? I was thinking maybe there is a problem with a startup executable? I'm not sure though.)

I've tried tweaking some stuff in the Publish section of my project , such as un-checking the box that says "use .deploy extension files" (I don't know why, I've been grasping at straws here) I've been looking into some other installers such as NSIS but I don't know how to compile a list of files to include in other installers and I feel like that won't solve the problem anyway because I've gotten ClickOnce to work with me before.

On one computer there was an error report that said something about 'deployment and application do not have matching security zones.'

> > Game.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
> >     + Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.

It's getting late so if I need to provide more information let me know.

Comment: Which part isn't working? The install (setup.exe) or your game after the install (game.exe)?

Comment: The install setup works fine I think as it runs through the whole install process. But my desktop icon and my start menu icon don't run anything. I'm going to try a few more things to see if I can get an error report and go from there.

Comment: I tried setting up a try-catch in an attempt to see if something is crashing without my knowledge and acquire some info with a messagebox , but I'm not getting anything from that. I also downloaded XNA refresh to see if that was a problem and created an Inno installer but the problem seems to be with my executable file as the same problem occurs. When I click on it the game shows up in my process tab of my Task Manager until it reaches 10,000k then it disappears. Though the game never shows up as an Application on my Task Manager.

Comment: One other thing, the 'Application' tab on my Publish screen doesn't have anything in my 'Target Framework' bar, also I can't change it or use the drop down arrow to select anything. It's just blank. I don't know if that is a problem or how to fix it but I figured I would include that bit of info.

Comment: Okay, I was able to get the game to run after I commented out my ScreenManager class references and made it only play the blank blue screen. Which means something in my code is not running properly right? I'm going with that and if I come up with something I will update this post. Crossing my fingers.

Answer (score 2):

ClickOnce can be a fickle thing. There are times that I've had errors occur that could only be solved by recreating an entire Windows user profile. Because there are so many different options for ClickOnce, it's going to be hard for me to diagnose your exact issue, so I can only offer what options I used to successfully install via ClickOnce.

- Publishing Folder: local folder
- Installation Folder URL: blank
- Install Mode: offline
- Application Files

  - Make sure the Publish Status of your game files is set to Include (Auto)
  - Make sure the Publish Status of the XNA libraries is set to Prerequisite (Auto)
- Click Prerequisites

  - Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
  - Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0
  - Windows Installer 3.1
- Do not check for updates
- Everything else default under Options (publisher/suite name shouldn't affect anything)
- Specify the version number
- Publish Now

Install the game through the setup.exe provided in the publish location. I always distribute every file that is publishes. However, you can clean up old versions in the "Application Files" folder if you don't want the history to be distributed.

You can double check the "Application Files" folder to see if your version got published correctly (look at the files that were deployed and see if they match your project contents).

Comment: ClickOnce can be a fickle thing. +1 I use Wix for XNA now, another (easier but paid) option is advanced installer

Comment: I think everything is there, though I don't see the xml files for my spritefonts even though I set there build action to content I can't see an option to include them in the application files. Other than that I don't see an executable for the game itself, however in the application folder I see a game.exe.deploy file that I can't open even after installation. So I am missing my xml files and my game executable I guess? I have it set to 'Include(Auto)' but I can't change that anyway.

Comment: I need a working exe file for my game if I am going to use Inno (I can use Inno setup pretty well) but I'm not sure what all I need to add to the inno setup in order to propery install it. I see a exe file for my game under the \release folder along with the content and the other folders but it doesn't do anything even after I install the game.

Comment: It shows up in my task manager process section but only at 800k and nothing happens from there. I wish something would crash or give me an error so I could have something to go off of.

Comment: I can help you some more when I get to my dev box in an hour. Keep in mind that the "published" files from ClickOnce doesn't contain a running executable. You need to first run the setup which will then install everything to a hidden folder in your Windows User Profile. That resulting folder will contain your game executable and content with proper file extensions.

Comment: Here is another weird thing it does on one of the computers. When we try to execute, the screen goes black and the cursor is 50% bigger than normal.